# How to avoid TypeScript error when using closest() in React Testing Library?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my unit test, I am trying to select the following `div` so that I can click on it.

```html
<div>
  <h1>Avocado Toast</h1>
  <p>Avocado toast served on country bread, served with a side of veggies</p>
</div>
```

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770973/parent-node-in-react-testing-library) I tried to use `getByText()` in combination with `closest()`:

```
const avocadoToast = screen.getByText('Avocado Toast').closest('div');
userEvent.click(avocadoToast);
```

However Typescript complains on the second line that `avocadoToast` could be null (because `closest()` could return a null):

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

I have worked around the problem by adding a non-null assertion operator to this line:

```
userEvent.click(avocadoToast!);
```

However I feel that I am not structuring the test correctly. Is there a better way?

Comment: What does clicking on the div do? If the answer's anything other than "nothing": why's it just a div?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The div is meant to be a menu item in a menu. It is sitting inside a list (`<li>`). It is styled as a card. What would be the most accessible way to code the div?

Comment: I found several articles on making accessible cards, e.g. [this one](https://kittygiraudel.com/2022/04/02/accessible-cards/). I will use one of these solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and guidance from [Kent C. Dodds](https://x.com/kentcdodds/status/1708784577421119950?s=20), I decided on the following solution because of its simplicity:

```
const avocadoToast = screen.getByText('Avocado Toast').closest('div');

// use an invariant to verify that avocadoToast is not null
// this now satisfies TypeScript in the last line
if (avocadoToast === null) {
  // fail the test right here so that rest of the test is not complicated
  throw new Error("Couldn't find Avocado Toast");
}

userEvent.click(avocadoToast);
```

Note that the correct way to fail a test in Jest is to throw an error (see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176642/in-jest-how-can-i-make-a-test-fail))

A more elaborate way to fix the solution would be to make the original HTML (intended to be a card) more accessible by using the guidelines [here](https://kittygiraudel.com/2022/04/02/accessible-cards/).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple nullcheck before asserting the click event:

```
const avocadoToast = screen.getByText('Avocado Toast').closest('div');
if (avocadoToast != null) {
    userEvent.click(avocadoToast);
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but this has two issues:

1. I will need and else clause in case avocadoToast is null, otherwise the test will silently pass
2. If I need to do more things in the test to check the result of clicking, the block becomes complicated. For example, if I need to do a similar selection in the block, I will have one more nested if.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the desired component is a `div` is an implementation detail, and testing it isn't recommended.

As noted in the [Guiding Principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/)

> testing the application components in the way the user would use it

and user would click a component because it has some text, label, image with alt text etc. If none of these applies you can use [ByTestId](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid)

Comment: I would like to avoid `ByTestId`. The div is meant to be a menu item in a menu. I would like the user to be able to click anywhere in the div to order that item. It is sitting inside a list (<li>). It is styled as a card. What would be the most accessible way to code the div? If I can do that, then selecting it would be easier.

Comment: I found several articles on making accessible cards, e.g. [this one](https://kittygiraudel.com/2022/04/02/accessible-cards/). I will use one of these solutions.